# DXA throws warning: Entity of type webapp.model.entity.RichContent does not contain a field named Content

Tags: dxa, java

In DXA 1.4 (Java) in my logs I see the following warning:

> 12:04:35.304 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] WARN  c.s.w.common.impl.markup.MarkupImpl - Entity of type webapp.model.entity.RichContent does not contain a field named Content.

How can I resolve this warning, as the views and models are outputting expected content.

**Model:**

```
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "RichContent", vocabulary = SDL_CORE) 
public class RichContent extends AbstractEntityModel {

    @JsonProperty("Content")
    private RichText content;

    public RichText getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(RichText content) {
        this.content = content;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How does the View code that uses this View Model look?

Answer (score 1):

The views contained Experience Manager Markup that was written with capital C, this should be lower case. @Rick thanks for pointing me to the views :)

```
<span ${markup.property(entity.sideArticle.content, "content")}>
```